# Comparisons of Solving Speed of QP & SOCP

Tags: computational-complexity, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming, second-order-cone-programming

For two same scale optimization problem, quadratic programming (QP) and second-order cone programming (SOCP), which one is faster to solve? As far as I know, the computational complexity of QP and SOCP are the same. But according to my test, the QP seems to be much faster than SOCP. What is the reason?

Comment: It will in practice depend on so many things: what solver you use, structure of the problem, numerical issues, what accuracy you compute to, and so on. There is no generic answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Are their computational complexity is both $O(n^{3.5})$?